# Where does Certbot serve up HTTP-01 challenges from?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am diagnosing a weird problem with some of my Ubuntu 14 LTS / Apache 2.4 machines with Certbot renewals.  Yes, I know Ubuntu 14 LTS is EOL soon; these are some of the straggler machines on the rebuild list.

Essentially, Certbot has been working well for a while on these machines, with renewals handled via a cron job.  Sometime between October and now, renewals have been failing with a 403 during the HTTP-01 challenge:

```
Detail: Invalid response from
http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/asdkjhfaklsjdfhalksdjfhkljasdfh:
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML
2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>403
Forbidden</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Forbidden</h1>\n<p"

To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
contain(s) the right IP address.
```

I have diagnosed the problem down to the .well-known directory being denied during the challenges because of Apache config (a `Require all denied` on /).

As a stop-gap, I am renewing the certs by hand by a temporary `Require all allowed` on /, but want to fix this properly.

So, where does Certbot actually serve up challenges from?  I tried a

```
<Directory /var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

but that didn't seem to work.  Because of the ratelimiting, guess-and-checks are slow.

Answer (score 0):

Requests are served up from /var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges. I think this is related to [certbot 0.28.0](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-0-28-0-release/76900) changes and EOL for [TLS-SNI-01](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/february-13-2019-end-of-life-for-all-tls-sni-01-validation-support/74209)

On my Ubuntu 14.04 / Apache 2.4.7 machines two things were needed.

I had to remove the root lockdown.  I edited /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf and also added in where the challenges get served from at the same time.

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges>
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart Apache and do a certbot dry run

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
$ sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

Then, put back the lockdown:

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride None
   Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges>
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Repeat the Apache restart certbot dry run

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
$ sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

At this point HTTP-01 challenges showed success.  In my case, I forced the issue of the TLS-SNI-01 shutdown, and force renewed my certs and made sure they used HTTP-01 challenges.

I really wish I knew why this sequence was needed, and not just a happy accident.  I don't think it was a fluke, though, since I needed to do the exact same steps on ~10 machines.  None of my newer Ubuntu servers needed this.